# Restore Git from a local copy

Tags: git, restore

We had a Git repo that was lost when the we forgot to back it up. One of us did a pull right before this happened and therefore has the latest code. Is it possible to rebuild the Git repo from a local copy of the sources? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your local copy *is* a Git repository on its own, containing the entire commit history (although only of the `master` branch). Creating an empty repository in the old location (`git init --bare whatever.git`), then running `git push` from the local copy should be sufficient.

Comment: Depending on the configuration, you may wrong w.r.t. the `master` branch. For me all branches and tags get fetched.